# php proxy no longer working

Tags: php, proxy

I have a custom php proxy class =>

```
class Proxy
{
    private $proxy,
            $header,
            $timeout,
            $agent;

    public function __construct($proxy, $header = null, $timeout = null, $agent = null) {
        $this->proxy   = $proxy;
        $this->header  = empty($header)  ? 1 : $header;
        $this->timeout = empty($timeout) ? 5 : $timeout;
        $this->agent   = empty($agent)   ? "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8" : $agent;
    }

    public function set_proxy($proxy) {
        $this->proxy = $proxy;
    }

    public function get_page($url, $referer = "http://www.google.com/") {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $this->header);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result = array();
        $result['exe'] = curl_exec($ch);
        $result['inf'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $result['err'] = curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Which I init like so =>

```
    $proxy = new Proxy("PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT");
    $content = $proxy->get_page($url);
```

And everything was working fine up until a couple of days ago. Now I keep getting error messages mostly related to `Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`.
Since I have no clue how an unmodified code could just stop working - I have no idea how to even debug this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT:
I know what 403 status code means, I'm just saying I get the 403 no matter what proxy I use and no matter which page I try to get using it.

Answer (score 0):

Know your status codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

`403` means "forbidden". I guess the one you proxied to, or from, decided, that you are not trustworthy enough to use their service. Or the real proxy you access has a password now.